# What is single-click (eval) mode (SharePoint 2010 service applications)?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, service-application

I'm writing a service application for SharePoint 2010. I've implemented the Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.IServiceAdministration in my service class. There's method called GetCreateApplicationOptions in this interface which returns the SPCreateApplicationOptions enumeration.

The enumeration has three distinct values, e.g. "None". The description of "None" reads: This service application is not created in single-click (eval) mode or shown/created in the farm configuration wizard.

I'm good with the farm creation wizard, but what is "single-click (eval) mode"? There seems to be no info around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is not a lot of help available. But based on description, it sounds like: Single-Click (eval) mode is applicable when you do NOT choose to install/configure SharePoint Farm yourself. For example, when you want to install everything on same machine on windows 7. And when you are not in single-click mode, SharePoint presents you a config wizard when you run the central admin first time, soon after installation.